# How to rebuild this? (iPhone Email App)

Tags: iphone, ios, email

I wanna rebuild this:
http://cdn.artoftheiphone.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/send-email-to-group-iphone.jpg

Include this features:
- complete scrollable screen
- same Design

Which controls to use? How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

hi it can be done in following ways.

1. Take  UIScrollView and add subviews to make GUI look like this in it.
2. Take UITableView and add cOustom cells.

Post here if you want further details about implementation of particular part of screen.

Answer (score 1):

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
[mailController setSubject:@" my subject"];

NSArray *setToRecipientsArray= [objectToEmailAddress componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSArray *setCCRecipientsArray= [objectCCEmailAddress componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSArray *setBCCRecipientsArray= [objectBCCEmailAddress componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

[mailController setToRecipients:setToRecipientsArray];
[mailController setCcRecipients:setCCRecipientsArray];
[mailController setCcRecipients:setBCCRecipientsArray];

[mailController setMessageBody:@" my message" isHTML:NO];
mailController.mailComposeDelegate = self;

UINavigationController *myNavController = [self navigationController];

if ( mailController != nil ) {
  if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]){
    myNavController presentModalViewController:mailController animated:YES];
  }
}
[mailController release];
```